# parallel test on two version of the same web app

Tags: testing, selenium, firefox-addon

I have two version of the same application, the older one A, is stable, the newest one B, added some new features to A,

I want to make a functional test of version B, and for each bug I found, I would verify if its a regression, or if the bug is also on version A

For this purpose, I wish to have a Firefox plugin (like selenium) that reproduce every user action in one tab to another, is there any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use selenium IDE in order to record user actions. But after steps are recorded you have to edit recorder steps, for example, change the 'click' command to the 'clickAndWait' and change base URL to version A's URL

Comment: but I wish to navigate simultaneously in the two versions, not to record in A and play in B